# How to make sidebar active menu and submenu with color

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 7.0 with Entity Framework Core with layout, all my views used layout and want show color remain on the active menu and submenu. I have tried using some of my css, jQuery and html but the result is not achieved. Please help me to achieve that.

View:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
    <li class="sidebar-header">
        Dashbord
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle bigmenu nav-link" href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="fa fa-home mr-1"></span>
            Home
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled nav-content" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li class="">
                <a class="smallmenu" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home" )">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="fa fa-hdd mr-1"></span>
            Insert
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled nav-content" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li class="">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Bank" )">Create Account</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "FundCode" )">Fund Code</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(59,125,221,.1),rgba(59,125,221,.0875) 
    50%,transparent);
    border-left-color: #3b7ddd;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
        setNavigation();
    });

   function setNavigation() {
     var path = window.location.pathname;
         path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
         path = decodeURIComponent(path);

         $("#sidebar .nav-item .nav-link").each(function () {
           var href = $(this).attr('href');
             if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
                $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
                }
            });

            $("#sidebar .nav-item ul li a").each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
                    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.nav- 
                      content').addClass('show');
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.nav-link').addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked by inspecting element that your css getting active? Or any of your exsiting css overridding that?

Comment: Thank you ***Md Farid Uddin Kiron***, for your suggestion. I have used CSS `#sidebar .nav-item .nav-link .active` and added `active` in the class of `li` tag. If I add `active` in any class of `li` tag that menu remains highlighted, However, if I apply the `active` in the class of all `li` tags, all menus and submenu will be highlighted in color. My desired outcome is to have only the clicked menu and its submenus highlighted in color.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I got your point, I going to  reproduce your issue, let's see how its behaving.